# UILabel in UITableViewCell is not resizing with Auto-Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am using Auto-layout. In Custom `UITableViewCell` added a `UILabel` with max width. I tried lots of method so that if the text is less . It should shrink or if text is more it should increase the height of the label .

I tried making `UILabel` in `CellForRowAtIndex` , Which was bad idea for obvious reasons.
Then i tried to get the `CGSize` with the help of Font and **Width** of the **Label** . Its shrinking but its not proper and for implementing it i have to Re-Draw the constrains . Basically the solutions i tried is not visually Appealing . Please help me with it . I have attached the picture of the present state of screen

Thanks [image]

Comment: what kind of constraints do you have? what is the parent view of that label? would it be multiline text?

Comment: @JulianKról : 'UITableViewCell' is parent View numberoflines property of  'UILabel' is 0 . I am having $ contains Leading , tail , top , bottom space.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Array of name
NSMutableArray *nameArray;

//take outlet of height constraint in custom cell; 
@property(weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeightConstraint;


-(void)viewDidLoad
{
_nameArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:,@"I am using Auto-layout. In Custom     UITableViewCell added a UILabel with max width.",@"Hi I am Rohit",@"I Like To Help Society" ,nil];
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomerRatingsCell *customerRatingsCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomerRatingsIdentifier"];
customerRatingsCell.labelName=[_nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
customerRatingsCell.headerLabelConstraint=[self getLabelHeight:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
return CustomerRatingsCell;

}
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      return [self getLabelHeight:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]+25 ;//plus 25 is remaining space apart from label height, if you are using the full height label equals to cell height then don't add it.

}



- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(NSString*)textLabel
{
    CGRect textRect = [textLabel boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:Avenir Roman size:12.0f]} context:nil];

    CGSize  expectedLabelSize = CGSizeMake(textRect.size.width, textRect.size.height);

    return expectedLabelSize.height;
}
```

Comment: Can you please comment it again and put this in Code section ?

Comment: I dont wanna change the height .. Width?

Comment: please send the screen shot i m  not getting your question